# ASP.NET making AJAX calls during long Postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a simple requirement in  a Web Page.

I have a button on the page which causes a postback and a lengthy process on server.So the post back waits for the server method to finish and takes    a long time. There is no option to queue the server action  asynchronous using Threadpool for example. This is mainly because at the server what is needed is to render several reports using the ReportViewer control which cannot be performed in a new thread.

So a compromise solution is to display a progress meter at client.I tried this using Ajax calls to server to determine job progress , but probably due to the fact we are in post back mode the Ajax call does not work.

Would appreciate any help 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

So can you make the main post back to an ajax post so that you can do something while waiting for the replay.

Comment: No I cannot as the reportviwer control is central to this

Comment: may be you can put it inside an Iframe and do your rest of work while it's loading.

Answer (score 0):

For a long operation, you could create a task that is processed inside your app in background and return a task identifier. This task identifier could be used:

1. to poll whether task completed or not using regular Web API like `GET /api/task/{taskId}`
2. to notify client via websocket when job is done

Optionally, you could store task progress and return progress value to feed control like progress bar

Answer (score 0):

> I believe there should be a simple way to tell IIS the webmethod should run on a separate thread

Not exactly... simple.
The `ReportViewer` control is a server-side control (created on the UI thread, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/425226/6309)), and as such, it can only be manipulated on the server side and during a postback.
You cannot directly interact with it using AJAX or client-side JavaScript. The control's state is maintained through ViewState and it requires a full postback to operate properly.

If you need to render the report during a long-running operation and then send it back to the client, you might have to:

- render the report to a format like PDF or Excel during the long operation, save it on the server, and then
- provide it to the client once it's ready.
- use AJAX polling to periodically check if the report is ready and update the progress bar accordingly.

That would involve steps similar to:

- When the button is clicked, make an AJAX request to a server-side method that starts the long-running operation. This method should render the report using the `ReportViewer` control, save it to a file on the server, and then return the unique key to the client.
- Start a JavaScript timer or interval that periodically makes AJAX requests to another server-side method that checks the progress of the operation. This method should return the current progress and whether the report is ready.
- When the report is ready, stop the JavaScript timer or interval, and provide a link to download the report.

For example:

- On the server side, in the code-behind file of your ASP.NET page (`.aspx.cs` file).

C# Server-side Code (`MyPage.aspx.cs`)

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Services;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string StartProcess()
    {
        string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = 0; // Initialize progress to 0

        // Start long process and render report
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
            // Simulate long process
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100); // Simulate work
                HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = i; // Update progress
            }

            // Render report using ReportViewer
            ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
            // Configure reportViewer as needed...
            reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType = string.Empty;
            string encoding = string.Empty;
            string extension = string.Empty;

            byte[] bytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

            // Save the report to a file
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports/" + key + ".pdf"), FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Session[key + "_ready"] = true; // Indicate that the report is ready
        });

        return key;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static object CheckProgress(string key)
    {
        return new {
            Progress = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session[key], // Get progress
            Ready = (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session[key + "_ready"] // Check if report is ready
        };
    }
}
```

- And the JavaScript/jQuery, client-side code and within a script tag in the `.aspx` file.
  You might place it in the head section, but it's often best to put script tags just before the closing body tag (`</body>`) to ensure the entire page has loaded before the script runs.

HTML and JavaScript Client-side Code (`MyPage.aspx`)

`MyPage.aspx`:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Start Process" />
        <progress id="myProgressMeter" max="100" value="0"></progress>
        <a id="downloadLink" style="display: none">Download Report</a>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#myButton").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "MyPage.aspx/StartProcess",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    // Start checking progress after starting the process:
                    var key = response.d;
                    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "MyPage.aspx/CheckProgress",
                            data: JSON.stringify({ key: key }),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(response) {
                                var progress = response.d.Progress;
                                $("#myProgressMeter").val(progress); // Update progress meter
                                if (response.d.Ready) {
                                    clearInterval(intervalId); // Stop checking progress
                                    // Show download link
                                    $("#downloadLink").attr("href", "Reports/" + key + ".pdf").show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }, 1000); // Check progress every 1 second
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```