# Trying to create progressbar, failing to have continous ajax calls during postback (blocking)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to build a progressbar trying to periodically run an ajax call from the client side while a postback is occuring.

However, it seems like the ajax call gets blocked, maybe because of to the postback. When the postback is finished, the http request with the ajax calls goes from pending to canceled.

Questions:

- Is it impossible to issue ajax calls during postback?
- Can I use the Session like I am doing in the following code example to keep track of the progress?

The webpage aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="TestProgressIndicator.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Test.TestProgressIndicator" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" 
      type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function start_progress()
        {
            var indicator = $(".progress-indicator");
            indicator.show();

            var num_div = indicator.find(".num");

            num_div.text("0%");

            setTimeout(update_progress, 80);

            function update_progress()
            {
                console.log("update_progress");
                $.post(
                    "Ajax/ProgressBarCallback.aspx"
                    , function (progress)
                {
                    num_div.text(progress + "%");

                    if (progress < 100)
                        setTimeout(update_progress, 80);
                    else
                        indicator.hide();
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"/>
        <div class="progress-indicator">
            <div class="num"></div>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnStart" runat="server" Text="Starta"
            OnClientClick="start_progress()" OnClick="btnStart_OnClick" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Ajax/ProgressBarCallback.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var progressObj = HttpContext.Current.Session["progress"];

        var progress = progressObj != null ? int.Parse(progressObj.ToString()) : 0;
        Response.ContentType = "text/json";
        Response.Write(progress);
    }
</script>
```

I am aware of this post being a duplicate of [ASP.NET making AJAX calls during long Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670508/asp-net-making-ajax-calls-during-long-postback) but it was 5 years since asked and it did not get any explanatory answers.

Comment: You would have to use ajax for the post data instead of a postback to make the progress bar ajax also work. Submitting a form through default browser process blocks everything else in page

Comment: MS developed a technology that makes it much easier to do this kind of thing, its known as SignalR: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr.

Comment: I haved used SignalR in a project, but I do not see how it would have any benefit over ajax.

Comment: I think the answer is to use an iframe with the form.

Comment: @AndersLindén its designed to act as a bi-directional pipe between the client and the server. It does exactly what you want to do with less effort.